# Which is the best search engine software for search a millions of data from database?

Tags: php, apache, elasticsearch, solr

I am developing a categories search application. and i have 5 million data, in future it might be increase and i am not able to decide which search engine software i should use.

Comment: You should take a look at [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/) which you've already tagged, it's amazing but can be difficult to setup

Comment: please tell me why it's best

Comment: S/O doesn't allow primarily opinion-based questions.I'd choose solr purely because my experience with it has been fruitful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle millions of data try **Elastic Search** one of the best search engine in the current market.it will handle large number of data(more than 2TB i used in my project.i.e nearly 100 millions)

https://www.elastic.co/